# Spin accumulation in Rashba-Edelstein effect

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-spin, topological-phase

I have been trying to figure out how to see the spin accumulation/spin current due to the Rashba-Edelstein effect from the k-space diagram. All that everybody says is that application of E-field shifts the Fermi circle in one direction and you have an accumulation of spins. I mean I see that there are more up spin in one direction over the other in the same direction as the charge current but shouldn't the spin accumulation in the orthogonal direction?

I would also like to check if spin accumulation is similar to spin current. From what I see, they are the same thing just that for accumulation, the electrons aren't flowing that's all. I was told that these are different things and for REE, you need to have an adjacent material to get spin current. I somehow don't really understand all this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.